# Как сделать случайную генерацию обьектов "волнами" с постоянным увеличением их количества по протяжению времени в определенной "зоне"

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Не знаю как сделать скрипт способный сделать определенную "зону", где будут появляться обьекты, которые идут "волнами" и со временем увеличиваются в количестве (обьекты, а не волны). Я новичок и всё ещё плохо разбираюсь в Unity,а найти в интернете то, что подошло бы под мой случай не смог;((

! https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/601772467765248011/722536201239789789/c3f82b2a0f0093eb.jpg

Comment: Можете нарисовать что вам нужно? Из вашего описания непонятно

Comment: Потому, что нужно не в Unity "разбиратся", а C# начать учить.

Comment: Скрипт который двигает ящики я сделал, а скрипт который должен был волнами спавнить у меня  просто их всех сразу спавнит ;(

Comment: @tym32167 я нарисовал (извините, что только сейчас сообщил)

Comment: Я понял, у вас проблема не в генерации ящиков, у вас проблема в организации самого принципа - создания ящиков волнами. Чтобы ответить надо знать юнити, я его к сожалению не знаю :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) > 0.95){
     doSomething();
}
```

`0.95` можно заменить на число, более близкое к `1`, если код срабатывает несколько раз, а можно вообще `> 0.95` заменить на `== 1`, но я считаю, что это не даст необходимой надежности (пропуск волн).